# Powershell - GetChilditem grab first result

Tags: powershell

I have an issue with a powershell script i have made. The purpose of the script is to gather information from various ressources, CMDB og and other systems and gather them in a combined report and send it.

I have everything working just fine, except one single ting that keeps bothering me. In my script, i do a lot of parsing and trimming in the information i get, at in some functions i need to get some XML files. Example:

```
$filter = "D:\WEC\Script\Rapportering\BigFixData\"
$xmlfiles = Get-ChildItem -path $filter -Filter "Bigfix_trimmed_JN.xml" -Recurse -Force |where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false } 
$xmlfile = $xmlfiles | ogv -OutputMode Single
```

There will always be only one file to grab, and thats why i use the Filter option and give the specific name. The code above will trigger a pop-up, asking me to select the file. It works fine except for the file picker popup. I want to get rid of that.

I then changed the code to this:

```
$filter = "D:\WEC\Script\Rapportering\BigFixData\"
$xmlfiles = Get-ChildItem -path $filter -Filter "Bigfix_trimmed_JN.xml" | Select-Object -First 1 |where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false }
```

This no longer shows the popup, but it does not seem to select the file. Resulting in a referenceObject error later in the script, because it is null.

the script is about 1000 lines and i have narrowed the error down to the command aboove.

Can anyone help me figuring out what i do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just `$xmlfile = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\WEC\Script\Rapportering\BigFixData\Bigfix_trimmed_JN.xml"` instead if there's only ever one file and the filename is known? Or even `$xmlfile = Get-Content -Path "D:\WEC\Script\Rapportering\BigFixData\Bigfix_trimmed_JN.xml"` if you also intend to read the file?

Comment: From the code that you've shown, I see that you've changed your criteria in the first example you did a 'Recurse' which will search in sub directories for your Xml file, in the second example you removed it. 
If you know that the file will be in the ..BigFixData folder why are you using the Recurse? also why are you piping to the where & filtering folders out when you specified an 'xml' extension? principally, you should only get files back, unless you have a folder with an '.xml' name.
I think you'll need to reveal more information to make it clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 7):

- Your 2nd command is missing the `-Recurse` switch, which may explain why you're not getting any result.
- While it is unlikely that *directories* match with a filter pattern as specific as `"Bigfix_trimmed_JN.xml"`, the more concise and faster way to limit matching to *files only* in PSv3+ is to use the `-File` switch (complementarily, there's also a `-Directory` switch).

```
$xmlfile = Get-ChildItem $filter -Filter Bigfix_trimmed_JN.xml -Recurse -File |
             Select-Object -First 1
```

You should add a check to see if *no* file was returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first *file*, you'll need to filter out the directories *before* piping to `Select-Object -First 1` - otherwise you run the risk of the first input element being a directory and your pipeline therefore evaluates to `$null`:

```
$xmlfiles = Get-ChildItem -path $filter -Filter "Bigfix_trimmed_JN.xml" | Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer} | Select-Object -First 1
```